How to dynamically create a protobuf object from string?
I have a protobuf definition like below,
message MyProto {
    optional string ip = 1; 
    optional int32 port = 2;
    optional Flags flags = 3;
}

message Flags {
    optional bool flag1 = 1;
    optional bool flag2 = 2;
}

My goal is to create a MyProto object from the below string:
ip:127.0.0.1
port:8080
Flags:
    flag1: True
    flag2: False

I can generate an "empty" object with my_proto = MyProto(), and can set the attribute of it by using
setattr(my_proto, "ip", "127.0.0.1")
setattr(my_proto, "port", 8080)

but cannot figure out how to "fill in" the Flags message into my_proto. Is there any general way to do that? By general way, I mean assume we need to figure out the message name of Flags from the string
Flags:
    flag1: True
    flag2: False

(because there could be other message definitions used in MyProto)

Is your problem how to assign nested values or how to parse the protobuf definition or the string containing the values?

@mkrieger1 yes, that's what I'm looking for.

I meant: which of the 3 is your problem

@mkrieger1, lol, my problem is to assign nested values (message here). Thanks

foo.proto:
syntax = "proto3";

message MyProto {
    optional string ip = 1; 
    optional int32 port = 2;
    optional Flags flags = 3;
}

message Flags {
    optional bool flag1 = 1;
    optional bool flag2 = 2;
}

protoc \
--python_out=${PWD} \
--pyi_out=${PWD} 
foo.proto

requirements.txt:
protobuf==5.28.2

main.py:
from foo_pb2 import MyProto,Flags

my_proto = MyProto(
    ip="192.168.1.1",
    port=8080,
    flags=Flags(
        flag1=True,
        flag2=False
    )
)

print(my_proto)

ip: "192.168.1.1"
port: 8080
flags {
  flag1: true
  flag2: false
}

You can use setattr but it's preferable to use the constructor of the class generated for each Messsage or reference fields directly (e.g. my_proto.ip = "foo") .
Because MyProto and Flags are both messages, both must be constructed before use.

DazWilkin, thanks for your reply. My problem is I want to dynamically figure out the type of the inner message to make it generic without explicitly import MyProto, Flags. Is there any way to do that?

You should be able to use google.protobuf.descriptor to walk through your protobuf structure. The documentation is scant though. IIRC I've answered another question on here to do so similar, I'll see whether I can uncover it.
